# DOT Graph/Graphviz -- getting top nodes and edges based on edge weight

Tags: graphviz, dot

What's the best way to get the top X percentage of edges (based on the weight of the edge) from a DOT graph. I couldn't find any Python function that already does this.

Edge weight is basically the content in the label.

```
123 -> 456[label="10s" fontsize=12 penwidth=1.0 ]
```

Comment: In your example, is 10 the weight (the value of the label attribute)?  [I'm confused because the language includes a weight attribute]

Comment: @sroush - updated to include weight attribute

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all edges have an explicit weight attribute.
Also assuming **dot** (other engines use floating point weights)
(**gvpr** is part of the Graphviz package)
This gives a list of unsorted weights & edge names.

```
gvpr 'BEG_G{int W,w;W=(float)getDflt($G,"E","weight");}E{if (!hasAttr($, "weight"))w=W;else w=$.weight;print(w," ",$.name);}' myfile.gv
```